# How can I read text from files and display them as list using widget/s in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text

may I ask a way how to make this work.

I have a text file named **questions.txt**.

This file contains the following questions:

1. How old are you?
2. Where do you live?
3. What is your age?

I want to load these questions from the file, and render them as a list in Flutter.

**questionnaires.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Questionnaires extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _QuestionnairesState createState() => _QuestionnairesState();
}

class _QuestionnairesState extends State<Questionnaires> {
    String q1 = "";
    String q2 = "";
    String q3 = "";
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                body: Center(
                    child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Text(q1),
                            Text(q2),
                            Text(q3)
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with the most basic way of retrieving the questions from a `.txt` file using `rootBundle.loadString`, then display it using a `ListView` widget.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Questions',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyAppScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppScreenState();
  }
}

class MyAppScreenState extends State<MyAppScreen> {
  List<String> _questions = [];

  Future<List<String>> _loadQuestions() async {
    List<String> questions = [];
    await rootBundle.loadString('path/to/questions.txt').then((q) {
      for (String i in LineSplitter().convert(q)) {
        questions.add(i);
      }
    });
    return questions;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _setup();
    super.initState();
  }

  _setup() async {
    // Retrieve the questions (Processed in the background)
    List<String> questions = await _loadQuestions();

    // Notify the UI and display the questions
    setState(() {
      _questions = questions;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Flutter Questions")),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _questions.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(_questions[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here are the sample list of questions.

**questions.txt**

```
"How old are you?"
"Where do you live?"
"What is your age?"
```

In the example code above, you are parsing the text file **line by line**, please see [LineSplitter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/LineSplitter-class.html). This is good for small and sample projects while you're testing out Flutter. But you should be able to update this implementation by following the official [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) of Flutter, on how you can read from and write on files.

Furthermore, if you want to go big with your Flutter project, you should look into ways on how you can host your questions online, eg. served via REST APIs, then retrieve it using the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) plugin for Flutter.

More on:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files
- https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Output:

[image: image-1]

Comment: hi joshua, this is a very big help by the way it works, but if i may to ask,, with line splitter, lets say i only want to get the 2nd question only instead of all the three, where do i need to put it in?

Comment: oh saw it now,, Text(_questions[index]); just change it to Text(_questions[1]); or 2,, bravo me LOL,, thank you po!!!! :)

Comment: oh crap, problem with that is that it shows all of the three questions are the same as to what i selected, meaning if i select 1 or 2, all three questions are 1 or 2 hahaha

Comment: simply removing it on listview fixes the problem, as the system thought that we are looking at the questionaires in a list

Comment: Is there a way that Read Text Files in Model List ?  List<model> , this model has 4 items ?